# Do startup scripts in Windows Server run asynchronously?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, google-compute-engine

As I'm debugging a startup script for a remote VM, I'm trying to run some commands that rely on the ones before. The errors I'm getting are inconsistent; sometimes, 2 out of 3 steps will run, sometimes none, sometimes all. After inserting while loops that force steps to check if previous steps have run, my script works more or less reliably.

This whole arrangement is somewhat awkward. Is there a way to make the startup scripts synchronous? Am I right in assuming that startup scripts run asynchronously in the first place?

Context: GCE, Windows Server 2012 R2. My script installs 3 things: Chocolatey, then Boxstarter, then calls a Boxstarter module. Chocolatey is a one-liner install, Boxstarter is installed via the choco package, and the Boxstarter module needs Boxstarter to be installed to run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you run an entire powerscript shell synchronously?](http://superuser.com/questions/1094046/how-do-you-run-an-entire-powerscript-shell-synchronously)

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers). If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether multiple logon scripts are run synchronously (or not) is up to how the policies are configured (you'd have to tell us how you have it configured).  By default they are run simultaneously.

If you just talking about the steps in a single script, then whether it's steps are synchronous or not is determined by the script itself.

Comment: By default then, should it be synchronous or asynchronous? I only have one script.

Comment: Depends completely on the script and what it's doing. If you're launching multiple, dependant processes, then you'll have to tell the batch file to wait for one process to finish, before starting the next.  How you do that depends on how the script was written, which language it was written in,  and which commands it's running.